# OpenXml Excel: throw error in any word after mail address

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I read Excel files using OpenXml. all work fine but if the spreadsheet contains one cell that has an address mail and after it a space and another word, such as:

> abc@abc.com abc

It throws an exception immediately at the opening of the spreadsheet:

```
var _doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(_filePath, false);
```

exception:

> DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackageException
>   **Additional information:**
>    Invalid Hyperlink: Malformed URI is embedded as a
>   hyperlink in the document.

Comment: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/issues/715

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is an open issue on the OpenXml forum related to this problem: [Malformed Hyperlink causes exception](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/issues/38)

In the post they talk about encountering this issue with a malformed "mailto:" hyperlink within a Word document.

They propose a work-around here: [Workaround for malformed hyperlink exception](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2014/08/19/handling-invalid-hyperlinks-openxmlpackageexception-in-the-open-xml-sdk.aspx)

The workaround is essentially a small console application which locates the invalid URL and replaces it with a hard-coded value;  here is the code snippet from their sample that does the replacement;  you could augment this code to attempt to correct the passed brokenUri:

```
private static Uri FixUri(string brokenUri)
{
    return new Uri("http://broken-link/");
}
```

The problem I had was actually with an Excel document (like you) and it had to do with a malformed http URL;  I was pleasantly surprised to find that their code worked just fine with my Excel file.

Here is the entire work-around source code, just in case one of these links goes away in the future:

```
 void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var fileName = @"C:\temp\corrupt.xlsx";
        var newFileName = @"c:\temp\Fixed.xlsx";
        var newFileInfo = new FileInfo(newFileName);

        if (newFileInfo.Exists)
            newFileInfo.Delete();

        File.Copy(fileName, newFileName);

        WordprocessingDocument wDoc;
        try
        {
            using (wDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(newFileName, true))
            {
                ProcessDocument(wDoc);
            }
        }
        catch (OpenXmlPackageException e)
        {
            e.Dump();
            if (e.ToString().Contains("The specified package is not valid."))
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(newFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                {
                    UriFixer.FixInvalidUri(fs, brokenUri => FixUri(brokenUri));
                }               
            }
        }
    }

    private static Uri FixUri(string brokenUri)
    {
        brokenUri.Dump();
        return new Uri("http://broken-link/");
    }

    private static void ProcessDocument(WordprocessingDocument wDoc)
    {
        var elementCount = wDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants().Count();
        Console.WriteLine(elementCount);
    }
}

public static class UriFixer
{
    public static void FixInvalidUri(Stream fs, Func<string, Uri> invalidUriHandler)
    {
        XNamespace relNs = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships";
        using (ZipArchive za = new ZipArchive(fs, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
        {
            foreach (var entry in za.Entries.ToList())
            {
                if (!entry.Name.EndsWith(".rels"))
                    continue;
                bool replaceEntry = false;
                XDocument entryXDoc = null;
                using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        entryXDoc = XDocument.Load(entryStream);
                        if (entryXDoc.Root != null && entryXDoc.Root.Name.Namespace == relNs)
                        {
                            var urisToCheck = entryXDoc
                                .Descendants(relNs + "Relationship")
                                .Where(r => r.Attribute("TargetMode") != null && (string)r.Attribute("TargetMode") == "External");
                            foreach (var rel in urisToCheck)
                            {
                                var target = (string)rel.Attribute("Target");
                                if (target != null)
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        Uri uri = new Uri(target);
                                    }
                                    catch (UriFormatException)
                                    {
                                        Uri newUri = invalidUriHandler(target);
                                        rel.Attribute("Target").Value = newUri.ToString();
                                        replaceEntry = true;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (XmlException)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                if (replaceEntry)
                {
                    var fullName = entry.FullName;
                    entry.Delete();
                    var newEntry = za.CreateEntry(fullName);
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(newEntry.Open()))
                    using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(writer))
                    {
                        entryXDoc.WriteTo(xmlWriter);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 13):

The fix by @RMD works great.  I've been using it for years.  But there is a new fix.

You can see the fix here in the [changelog](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/pull/793/commits/f5ff0dacb1565fe8c74c6e432ad537c83fcb4931#diff-06572a96a58dc510037d5efa622f9bec8519bc1beab13c9f251e97e657a9d4ed) for issue [#793](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/pull/793)

### Upgrade OpenXML to 2.12.0.

Right click solution and select *Manage NuGet Packages*.

### Implement the fix

1. It is helpful to have a unit test.  Create an excel file with a bad email address like test@gmail,com.  (Note the comma instead of the dot).
2. Make sure the stream you open and the call to SpreadsheetDocument.Open allows Read AND Write.
3. You need to implement a RelationshipErrorHandlerFactory and use it in the options when you open.  Here is the code I used:

```
    public class UriRelationshipErrorHandler : RelationshipErrorHandler
    {
        public override string Rewrite(Uri partUri, string id, string uri)
        {
            return "https://broken-link";
        }
    }
```

4. Then you need to use it when you open the document like this:

```
    var openSettings = new OpenSettings
    {
        RelationshipErrorHandlerFactory = package =>
        {
            return new UriRelationshipErrorHandler();
        }
    };
    using var document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(stream, true, openSettings);
```

One of the nice things about this solution is that it does not require you to create a temporary "fixed" version of your file and it is far less code.

### The Saga Continues!

The issue is finally fixed in version 3.  Not sure exactly how, but at least my unit test with bad URLs is passing!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately solution where you have to open file as zip and replace broken hyperlink would not help me.

I just was wondering how it is posible that it works fine when your target framework is 4.0 even if your only installed .Net Framework has version 4.7.2.
I have found out that there is private static field inside `System.UriParser` that selects version of URI's RFC specification. So it is possible to set it to V2 as it is set for .net 4.0 and lower versions of .Net Framework. Only problem that it is `private static readonly`.

Maybe someone will want to set it globally for whole application. But I wrote `UriQuirksVersionPatcher` that will update this version and restore it back in Dispose method. It is obviously not thread-safe but it is acceptable for my purpose.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;

namespace BarCap.RiskServices.RateSubmissions.Utility
{
#if (NET20 || NET35 || NET40)
        public class UriQuirksVersionPatcher : IDisposable
        {
            public void Dispose()
            {
            }
        }
#else

    public class UriQuirksVersionPatcher : IDisposable
    {
        private const string _quirksVersionFieldName = "s_QuirksVersion"; //See Source\ndp\fx\src\net\System\_UriSyntax.cs in NexFX sources
        private const string _uriQuirksVersionEnumName = "UriQuirksVersion";
        /// <code>
        /// private enum UriQuirksVersion
        /// {
        ///     V1 = 1, // RFC 1738 - Not supported
        ///     V2 = 2, // RFC 2396
        ///     V3 = 3, // RFC 3986, 3987
        /// }
        /// </code>
        private const string _oldQuirksVersion = "V2";

        private static readonly Lazy<FieldInfo> _targetFieldInfo;
        private static readonly Lazy<int?> _patchValue;
        private readonly int _oldValue;
        private readonly bool _isEnabled;

        static UriQuirksVersionPatcher()
        {
            var targetType = typeof(UriParser);
            _targetFieldInfo = new Lazy<FieldInfo>(() => targetType.GetField(_quirksVersionFieldName, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic));
            _patchValue = new Lazy<int?>(() => GetUriQuirksVersion(targetType));
        }

        public UriQuirksVersionPatcher()
        {
            int? patchValue = _patchValue.Value;
            _isEnabled = patchValue.HasValue;

            if (!_isEnabled) //Disabled if it failed to get enum value
            {
                return;
            }

            int originalValue = QuirksVersion;
            _isEnabled = originalValue != patchValue;

            if (!_isEnabled) //Disabled if value is proper
            {
                return;
            }

            _oldValue = originalValue;
            QuirksVersion = patchValue.Value;
        }

        private int QuirksVersion
        {
            get
            {
                return (int)_targetFieldInfo.Value.GetValue(null);
            }
            set
            {
                _targetFieldInfo.Value.SetValue(null, value);
            }
        }

        private static int? GetUriQuirksVersion(Type targetType)
        {
            int? result = null;
            try
            {
                result = (int)targetType.GetNestedType(_uriQuirksVersionEnumName, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                                        .GetField(_oldQuirksVersion, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                                        .GetValue(null);
            }
            catch
            {
#if DEBUG

                Debug.WriteLine("ERROR: Failed to find UriQuirksVersion.V2 enum member.");
                throw;

#endif
            }
            return result;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_isEnabled)
            {
                QuirksVersion = _oldValue;
            }
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

Usage:

```
using(new UriQuirksVersionPatcher())
{
    using(var document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fullPath, false))
    {
       //.....
    }
}
```

P.S. Later I found that someone already implemented this pathcher: https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Core/Util/UriPatcher.cs

Answer (score 0):

I haven't use OpenXml but if there's no specific reason for using it then I highly recommend LinqToExcel from [LinqToExcel](https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel). Example of code is here:

```
var sheet = new ExcelQueryFactory("filePath");
var allRows = from r in sheet.Worksheet() select r;
foreach (var r in allRows) {
var cella = r["Header"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: I have a specific reason. i dosent handle excel `table`s - by fields & rows but by excell - address cell with format and ect.

Answer (score 0):

In my case excel data in table format. So I copy all data and then paste as value in empty cell then delete all before data and then I can import data correctly.