# OpenXML SDK 2.0 to 3.0 migration and RelationshipErrorHandler

Tags: openxml-sdk

I am migrating from OXML 2.0 to the new 3.0.

They stated in their changelog:

"Removed OpenXmlSettings.RelationshipErrorHandlerFactory and associated types and replaced with a built-in mechanism to enable this"

I have this code:

```
                OpenSettings openSettings = new OpenSettings()
                {
                    RelationshipErrorHandlerFactory = RelationshipErrorHandler.CreateRewriterFactory(Rewriter)
                };

    private static string Rewriter(Uri partUri, string id, string uri)
        => $"http://unknown?id={id}";
```

Which, of course, does not work in the new version of OXML.
I could not find out this mechanism they talk about, so I do not how to rewrite this.
Perhaps someone has fallen also to this.
Thanks!

Comment: Any luck in figuring this out?

Answer (score 0):

This may seem like a bit of a non-answer, but so far it is working for me.

Remove the code for `RelationshipErrorHandlerFactory` and `RelationshipErrorHandler`.

That's it!  Less is more!

I have a unit test with a bad URL and it is passing!  (More like an integration test...)

See my other answer for more info about this problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64811821/1804678